# Passing parameters to a jQuery closure not working on Multisuggest plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, closures, autosuggest

I have a question of which someone might find this much simpler than I do, but alas, I don't have much experience with custom jQuery plugins.

The previous developer at my place of work left me with a lot of left-over plugins that don't seem to work very well, most which I've been able to fix but this which has been bugging me for a while.

It is a custom **Multiple Suggestion plugin (called multisuggest)** written in **jQuery**, and it has a **set of functions that it uses internally (**e.g. setValue to set the value of the box, or lookup to update the search***)*

It seems he's tried to call these plugin functions from an external script (this exteranl script specifically imports newly created suggestions into the multisuggest via user input and sets the value) like this:

```
this.$input.multisuggest('setValue', data.address.id, address);
```

This seems to call the function as it should, except the second and third parameters don't seem to be passed to the function (setValue receives nothing), and I don't understand how I can get it to pass these. It says it is undefined when I log it in the console. **The functions are set out like this (*I've only including the one I'm using and an internal function from multisuggest called select that actually works*):**

```
    MultiSuggest.prototype = $.extend(MultiSuggest, _superproto, {

    constructor : MultiSuggest, 
    select: function () { // When selecting an address from the suggestions
        var active, display, val;

        active  = this.$menu.find('.active');
        display = active.attr('data-display');
        val = active.attr('data-value');
        this.setValue(display, val, false); // This works, however when I do it as shown in the above example from an external script, it doesn't. This is because it doesn't receive the arguments.

    },
    setValue : function(display, value, newAddress) { // Setting the textbox value
        console.log(display); // This returns undefined
        console.log(value); // This returns undefined
        if (display && display !== "" &&
            value && value !== "") {
            this.$element.val(this.updater(display)).change();
            this.$hiddenInput.val(value);
            this.$element.addClass("msuggest-selected");
        }
        if(newAddress === false){
            return this.hide();
        }
    },
});
```

Why does it listen to the function, but not the values passed to it? Do I need to include an extra line of code somewhere to define these arguments?

Anyone with jQuery experience would be of great help! This is bottlenecking progress on a current project. Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:**
I've missed out the code of how the arguments are trying to be passed from the external script to the internal function of the plugin. Here is the plugin definition with how the external call is handled, can anyone see a problem with this?

```
$.fn.multisuggest = function(option) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('multisuggest'), options = typeof option === 'object' && option;
        if (!data) {
            $this.data('multisuggest', ( data = new MultiSuggest(this, options)));
        } else if (typeof(option) === 'string') {
            var method = data[option];
            var parameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

            method.apply(this, parameters);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: The inheritance model looks a little odd but presumably works otherwise your log statements would not be working at all. Is `setValue()` called from elsewhere, other than `select()`? Try tracking down all the calls and check each one passes valid `display` and `value`.

Comment: I've modified the question as I haven't made it clear where I have actually been calling setValue from. The first snippet of code I showed you `this.$input.multisuggest('setValue', data.address.id, address);` is actually being called from an **external script**. Namely a script that creates new addresses & imports it into the suggestion box.

Where I logged display & value, when I select something from the multiple input box, it passes the variables easily, but obviously it is because it is within it's scope. It is just as I said, when called from an external script, that function doesn't work

Comment: The (immediate) problem would appear to be in the external script. It would appear that at the point `this.$input.multisuggest(...);` is called, `data` and `address` don't yet exist. I would suspect an asynchronicity issue, eg that line needs to be moved inside a callback or `.done()` handler.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, however I have included a data.success callback from the ajax call I do to create a new address, and I have logged data & address & they both have data before they are sent to multisuggest. I have included the plugin definition where it handles the arguments at the bottom of my question, it seems there is some error in the code here possibly as it doesn't seem to be receiving those parameters...

Comment: That's the plugin's "supervisor" and it doesn't look right at all. Try the version from jQuery's sample plugin. I'll post it in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "usual" plugin supervisor looks like this :

```
// *****************************
// ***** Start: Supervisor *****
$.fn.multisuggest = function( method ) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist in jQuery.' + pluginName );
    }
};
// ***** Fin: Supervisor *****
// ***************************
```

All the looping through `this` should be inside the method functions, not in the supervisor.

I'm a little worried that `new MultiSuggest(...)` appears in the current supervisor. That sort of thing is totally unconventional. The original author clearly had something in mind.

Comment: I think I've got it. The original supervisor also performs an `init` action. The init code needs to be moved to a proper 'init' method.

Comment: Where should I be setting this array of "methods", as this doesn't seem to be set in the plugin itself... I assume this is standard, but the way he has written this plugin, there is no methods array included. Should I create the array?

Comment: There is also a proper init method... Perhaps I should include the entire script in an external paste, as there is a lot of extra code that obviously hasn't been seen?

Comment: Good idea, I need to see the whole plugin if possible.

Comment: SixteenStudio, I'm about to disappear for a few hours. Friends are due for elevensies, then I'm off to work. Back about 17:00 GMT.

Comment: Thank you Beetroot, you've been extremely helpful:
There are actually 2 scripts involved. A multisuggest (multiple suggestions whilst typing) and an address-selector (allows user to create new suggestions). I've included both scripts in this paste for you to have a look at. Thanks again:

http://pastebin.com/2X4QXgZi

Comment: No problem, there are other parts of this system I can work on. Thanks for all your help and I've left this paste up for a day, so if you could have a look at it when you have some spare time, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks man!

Comment: I've fixed my problem by instead of setting the new address as the value using the setValue function, I simply set the value & data-value attributes on the field to my address and id, and then re-initiliaze the plugin so that it takes these as it's default value. I am still curious as to why setValue would still not work, and I will still accept it as the answer when the problem is solved :)

Comment: SixteenStudio, I'm back and just read your last message. I'll see if I can spot the problem though I won't bust myself now that you've found a workaround.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your attentiveness regardless, great developer!

Comment: SixteenStudio, I have had a good look at the code and can't come to any firm conclusion. Now I have seen the whole plugin, the supervisor looks more sensible though it's still under suspicion. I'm guessing that (a) the two internal calls to `setValue()` work OK, and (b) `setValue()` is the only (non-static) method subject to an external call (ie the problem area). If I'm right on both points, then the supervisor is well and truly in the dock. My earlier suggestion to replace the supervisor with the more familiar version was incorrect. It looks as if the existing one needs to be fixed.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it is as close as it gets really, and it clearly is an issue with the supervisor :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, it's a tricky one. I wish I could have been more definitive. Needs a good solid interactive debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the jQuery plugin function which is attached to `$.fn['multisuggest']`, that function is probably only taking and passing one parameter.

Comment: The plugin itself is already extending, would I need to extend it externally to pass the parameters I need to it?